# What occurs when three properties are bounded in a cycle?

Tags: binding, javafx

I have bound three properties forming a binding cycle. But I'm not sure how to interpret the results.

```
DoubleProperty d1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1);
DoubleProperty d2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(2);
DoubleProperty d3 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(3);

d1.bind(d2.multiply(2)); //d1 = 4
d2.bindBidirectional(d3);//d2 = 3, d1 = 6
d3.bind(d1);
```

Finally, the output is

> d1 = 12.0, d2 = 6.0, d3 = 12.0

The question is why the value of d1, d2, and d3 is not equal to 24, 12, and 24?

What is the rule to stop the binding?

I think I get an error here.

Comment: You "think" you get an error? Do you get an error or not? If you do, what is it?

Comment: I thought I would get an error, but not, I didn´t get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding detects an endless loop in your binding. Your first value which was changed is d3. After d3 was changed the second time it stops to calculate the next value. So the rule is simply if a property is changed the second time, is is a loop and the calculation stops. Just debug this code to see what happens if you are interested in ;)